# Is it true that God himself came to saint Ekanatha's house to do his work?

Tags: saint

I have heard the folk story that Ekanath was very busy in the social-cultural reformation of society.  Also, many people came to his house for the meal every day. So, He and his wife too busy for the housework.

Therefore Lord himself came  Ekanatha's house to do his housework. I am not sure about this is a real story or not? Is there any reference?